# ostream_iterator with pointers

Tags: c++, stream

Let

Foo.hpp :

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    void print() const;
    protected:
    vector<Bar<string, int>*> bar_;
};

void Foo::print() const
{
    copy(bar_.begin(), bar_.end(), ostream_iterator<Bar<string, int>*>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Bar.hpp :

```
class Bar
{
    public:
    template <typename K, typename U>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Bar<K, U>&);
}

template <typename Key, typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Bar<Key, T>& bar)
{
    return out << "FOOBAR";
}
```

Where bar_ is an attribute of Foo and is a vector of pointers to Bar elements. Assume bar_ has one element, then the output of :

```
Foo foo;
foo.print();
```

is the address of the element in bar_, instead of "FOOBAR". If I wouldn't use pointers, the output would be "FOOBAR" What I'm trying to achieve here is to print "FOOBAR" for each pointer of bar_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
template <typename Key, typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Bar<Key, T>* bar)
{
    return out << *bar;
}
```